# SUMIF SUM IF Formula not calculating correct - counting blank cells

Tags: excel, countif, sumifs

I Have a sheet ive been working on that has proven to work well other than one cell.  The cell is to count all the cells that contain a date within the month of JANUARY.  The current Range is B2:B30, it gives me the number 29 even though the cells are blank. I have the same formula just up by a month for the entire year without issue.  I would love help on this!

FORMULA
=SUM(IF(MONTH(B2:B30)=1,1))

When I put in dates anywhere in that range it does bring the count down below 29 as if its counting blank cells. I have it on an identical sheet just with a different year and no issues!

[29 count even though they're blank](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ggWQf.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just need to check for blanks - a "zero" date is indeed in January (Jan 1900 specifically).

```
=SUM(IF(MONTH(B2:B30)=1,IF(B2:B30>0,1,0),0))
```

Comment: Apparently Excel thinks "Nested IFs good, logical functions bad" for this kind of array formula.

Comment: That worked perfectly!  what does the second IF function say so I can know how to apply it later?  Just starting to understand Excel formulas

Comment: It's just checking that there is some positive value in the cells. Blanks evaluate at zero. I added an "else" value to both IF statements (the third parameter, `,0`) but I think the default is zero anyway, it's just my style.